# Orbits of the action of $A_6$ on $\mathbb{P}_2$

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry

By a paper of Scott Crass  http://xxx.lanl.gov/pdf/math/9903111v1.pdf 
we know that $A_6$ (Permutation on 6 elements) is an automorphism group of $\mathbb{P}_2$ which fix a sextic. What is the geometry of this action i.e., what are the orbits of this action explicitly.

Comment: Is $A_6$ the symmetric group? That type of notation is usually reserved for the alternating group, i.e., the subgroup of even symmetries.

Comment: I mean the simple group with 360 elements. Yes. Symmetric.

Comment: You mean "Yes. Alternating."  ("Symmetric" would be $S_6$, not $A_6$.)
This group has a nontrivial triple cover $3.A_6$, with a faithful 
$3$-dimensional representation that projectivizes to an action of 
$A_6$ on ${\bf P}^2$.  There's some information and reference in the 
Wikipedia page on the "Valentiner group": 
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Valentiner_group
$\phantom\infty$ It's known that $A_6$ and $A_7$ are the only simple alternating groups
whose Schur multiplier is cyclic of order $6$; the others have
Schur multiplier ${\bf Z}/2{\bf Z}$.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As noted in the comments, this is a classical object, credited to
[Valentiner 1889]; the [paper
by Robert Crass](http://arxiv.org/pdf/math/9903111v1.pdf) that you cite refers to that paper and also to work of
Wiman [1895] and Fricke [1926] that should contain the answer to your
question, and Crass himself collects those answers starting on page 13.

The generic point of course has trivial stabilizer.  For each of the $45$
involutions $i \in A_6$ there's a fixed line $l_i$, and most points on each
$l_i$ are stabilized by just $i$, and thus have an orbit of size $180$.
[The normalizer $N_i$ is an $8$-element dihedral group, and $N_i/\{1,i\}$
is a Klein four-group acting on $l_i$; the orbit of the generic point on $l_i$
consists of its four images under that four-group, and four further images
on each of the other $44$ lines, for a total of $4 \cdot 45 = 180$.]
There are two special orbits of size $60$, and one each of size $45$ and $36$,
with dihedral stabilizers of size $6$, $8$, $10$ [NB there are two
conjugacy classes of $S_3$'s in $A_6$, related by an outer automorphism
of $S_6$]; when the stabilizer is dihedral of size $2n$, the point
is at the intersection of $n$ lines $l_i$ corresponding to the $n$
non-central involutions in the group.  There is also a $90$-point orbit
with cyclic stabilizer of order $4$.

You asked for "the orbits of this action explicitly"; if you want
explicit coordinates, you must specify coordinates for ${\bf P}^2$
and matrices for (generators of) the projective action of $A_6$.
Fortunately Crass gives these coordinates and generators on pages 4ff. $-$
actually two choices ("octahedral cordinates" and "icosahedral coordinates",
citing and slightly modifying Fricke [1926]).

Alternatively you could go to the ATLAS [1985] entry for $A_6$,
and go to the "$2 \times 3 . A_6$" paragraph of the Constructions section.
This gives coordinates for the $45$-point orbit on the
lift of the Valentiner group to a complex reflection group of
$3 \times 3$ matrices (#27 in the list of Shephard and Todd [1954]).
Regarding them as dual coordinates for $45$ lines $l_i$, you should be
able to compute all the intersections that give orbits shorter than $180$,
and also to find explicit matrices for the involutions $i$ that
generate the group (and thus in particular the $4$-cycles that
stabilize the $90$-point orbit).

**References** (mostly from Crass):

[ATLAS 1985] John H[orton]. Conway et al.:
*ATLAS of Finite Groups: 
Maximal Subgroups and Ordinary Characters for Simple Groups.*
Oxford: Clarendon Press, 1985.

[Fricke 1926] Robert Fricke: *Lehrbuch der Algebra* 2.  Vieweg, 1926.

[Shephard and Todd 1954] G.C. Shephard and T.A. Todd:
Finite Unitary Reflection Groups,
*Canadian Journal of Mathematics* **6** (1954), 274$-$304.

[Valentiner 1889] H. Valentiner:
De endelige Transformations-Gruppers Theori,
*Videnskabernes Selskabs Skrifter, Sjette Raekke, Naturvidenskabelig og
Mathematisk Afdeling 2.*  Bianco Lunos, 1889.

[Wiman 1895] Anders Wiman:
Ueber eine einfache Gruppe von 360 ebenen Collineationen,
*Mathematische Annalen* **45** (1895), 531$-$556.